# aggregate rows into tensorflow variable

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network, tensorflow, tensorflow-slim

I have a tf.Variable tensor that should work as a result aggregator.

The idea is that I will execute an operation on the graph with batches of data and the results should be appended as new rows to my result Variable.

Because at the beginning the variable should be empty, I initialize it like this:

```
result_tensor = tf.Variable(0, expected_shape=[0, 5], dtype=tf.float32)
```

Then, what I do is concatenate the new rows along the axis 0 (as new rows):

```
total_output = tf.concat([result_tensor, operation], 0)
```

Finally, I reassign the variable:

```
assign_op = tf.assign(result_tensor, total_output, validate_shape=False)
```

However, when all of this is run, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 2 for 'concat_1' (op: 'ConcatV2') with input shapes: [], [?,25088], [].
```

Can you guys help me to find the obvious thing that I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're creating `result_tensor` by feeding a 0. Which means your `result_tensor` is a scalar value and not a row as you expect. The `expected_shape` property doesn't fix that.

Instead, you should declare `result_tensor` to be `tf.zeros([1, 25088])` as 25088 seems to be the size of the rows you want to append. Then, once you have all your results, just remove the first row by slicing.

Note: The `tf.Variable` class is not meant to store results but to add trainable values to your graph. In all my experiments with Tensorflow, I never had to use it. Not even once. The `tf.layers` module usually contains all I need.

Comment: Where should I store the results then? Keeping in mind that later I'll need to do operations on them.

Comment: I showed you in my answer how you could do it. You need to do operations on them. Sure. But you don't need to update the values inside when training your graph, do you ?